# Is there a way to retrieve the time of the most recent log compaction on a Kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka

For monitoring and debugging purposes, we would like to be able to programmatically retrieve the timestamps at which log compaction was performed for a specific Kafka topic. I suppose a possible solution would be to have a service reading the log output of a Kafka broker and extracting the times at which the following messages are logged:

```
[2023-04-03 11:07:28,319] INFO Cleaner 0: Cleaning log orders-0 (cleaning prior to Mon Apr 03 11:07:21 UTC 2023, discarding tombstones...
```

But maybe there is a more direct approach?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, parsing those logs is the best option, as those events are per-broker. We used Splunk, but Elasticsearch, or any TSDB should work as well.

The LogCleaner thread may expose JMX metrics, but I don't think granular timestamp information is included.